# iOS 16 + | Push Notification Calls App Delegate Method | didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios16

I am getting a weird issue on iOS 16.3.1 My application is killed and not in background.
But when I receive a push notification, without tapping the notification or interacting with that. The AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called itself.
This is weird cause app plays the sound of splash screen in the background. But when I swipe the application to see the apps in background its not there. And when I open the app from icon its clearly visible that it was started no splash etc.

Has anyone faced the same problem?
Any help will be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: I have same issue and I haven't found a solution yet